# Get only few value from multiple choice

Tags: c++

I have offered multiple input choices to the user. I want the user to pick two choices, and I want to store the choices in `num1` and `num2`:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"This programme will calculate the profit and loss "<<endl;

    int num1,num2;
    cout<<"What are the given terms "<<'\n'
        <<"Please enter any two known terms to find the other remaining unknown terms"<<endl;
    cout<<" Cost price:-"<<endl;
    cout<<" selling price"<<endl;
    cout<<" profit "<<endl;
    cout<<"profit percentage "<<endl;
    cout<<" loss "<<endl;
    cout<<" losspercentage "<<endl;
    // i want to store any of the two values in num1 and num2;
}
```

Comment: Allergic to formatting? Go ahead and perform this task. There's no question here.

Comment: Where is the input bit?

Comment: which parameters you would like to store in num1 and num2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick two choices num1 and num2 is created now you write:

```
    cin>>num1;
    cin>>num2;
```

You can store this in a file by using fstream file and typing

```
    ofstream file;
     file.open ("report.txt", ios::app);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, in which way this is an answer to the OPs (non existent) question?

Comment: There is nothing to do with OPs over here in this question. Could you please also give a aswer

Comment: _'Could you please also give a aswer'_ Of course no, since there's no definite question asked?!? (What do you think **OP** means here BTW??)

Comment: **OP** means the questions operator here. You might want to have a look at SOs help pages ...